# How to preserve string literal encoding between different systems?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I'm writing code on a windows machine, but when I run it on Linux, non-English characters are printed incorrectly to stdout.

The goal is to print the character Ä.

Source code:

```
import sys
import locale
import platform

print('Ä')

print(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
print(platform.platform())
print(platform.python_version())
```

Output on system A, the computer I wrote the code on:

```
Ä
utf-8
cp1252
Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
3.11.1
```

Output on system B, where I want my code to run:

```
Ã„
UTF-8
UTF-8
Linux-3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-7.9-Maipo
3.6.8
```

I suspect the it's related to the cp1252 encoding, but shouldn't python 3 use UTF-8 by default? Can the older python version on the Linux system have an effect?

Also, if I run the following program with an input of 'Ä':

`print(input("type something: "))`

the output on system A is:

```
type something: Ä
Ä
```

and on system B:

```
type something: Ä
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
print(input("type something: "))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

How can I get Ä to work on the Linux system as well?

Comment: That's weird - it looks like the *Linux* system is interpreting your UTF-8 output as cp1252.

Comment: I suspect the problem happened when you copied the file between systems.

Comment: @Barmar I used filezilla to transfer the file. It seems filezilla can cause encoding problems for utf-8, but generally speaking files with special characters transfer fine between these to systems. I have no idea if fz is the problem.

Comment: What editor did you use to create the script?

Comment: @Andj I used Visual studio code, the status bar displays UTF-8 as the encoding used.